# How to wait query result in nodejs to update another query result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, geospatial

Want to add offers query data in current user data to return the users with offers they have created. In response users offers always null

Fetch all user in range distance:

```
   // Execute Query and Return the Query Results
   query.exec(function(error, associate_users) {
          var array_users = new Array();

          for (var i = 0; i < associate_users.length; i++) {
                var current_user = formatUser(associate_users[i], true);
                var user_id = current_user['user_id'];

                offers_controller.getUserOffers(user_id, latitude, longitude, distance, function(error, result_offers) {

                      current_user['offers'] = result_offers;
                      console.log(result_offers);
                      console.log(current_user); 
                       //Users logs show offers but in array there is no offers in api
          });
          array_users.push(current_user);
       }

       response.json({

           error: false,
           user: array_users,
            message:message.userListed
       });
 });
```

Fetch all offers with associate users in range distance:

```
var query = offers.find({'type':'Point', offer_by:user_id});

// Execute Query and Return the Query Results
query.exec(function(error, result_offers) {

    if (error) {

        return callback(error, null);
    } else {

        var array_offers = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < result_offers.length; i++) {

            array_offers.push(formatOffers(result_offers[i]));
        }
        return callback(null, array_offers);
    }
});
```

Comment: It is not very clear what exact question you're asking for help with.  Can you please state exactly what problem you have and what you want help with?

Comment: In first query which give me all th user based on location 

After that i process the users array which return by first query, and get offers related to that user from another query but try to put offers result in user data


Offers in users array which return in response give me blank.

Please help try to understand...

Comment: Simply I want to return offers in user data which is result of first query and offers are result of second query at the time when I process first query data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest your callbacks:

```
query.exec(function(error, associate_users) {
  if (error) {
    return callback(error, null);
  } else {
     //TODO Your users loop code
     query.exec(function(error, result_offers) {
       if (error) {
         return callback(error, null);
       } else {
         //TODO Combine the data however you need
         response.json({
           error: false,
           user: array_users,
           message: message.userListed
       });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: @Nike I unable to run nested query because 
users come from user controller and offer come from offer controller offers_controller.getUserOffers(user_id, latitude, longitude, distance, function(error, result_offers)  {  current_user['offers'] = result_offers; console.log(result_offers); console.log(current_user); //Users logs show offers but in the array, there are no offers in API });